# Change the color of error bars

Tags: plotting, color, around

I need to have a plot with different colors for each data. Since I couldn't have all the data in one Plot with different colors, I drew each separately and used the Show command for the overall display, but one of the data does not appear in the final Plot and I don't know where the problem is?!

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
val1 = ImportString["0.12    10   0.01   0
0.12    10   0.01   0"];
val2 = ImportString["0.12    20   0.01   0
0.12    20   0.01   0"];
val3 = ImportString["0.12    30   0.01   0
0.12    30   0.01   0"];

p1 = ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#3, #4}} & @@@
val1, IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"m"}, {0.1, 0.9}]]
p2 = ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#3, #4}} & @@@
val2, IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> Green, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"n"}, {0.1, 0.9}]]
p3 = ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#3, #4}} & @@@
val3, IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> Black, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"s"}, {0.1, 0.9}]]



list1 = {{0.12, 0}, {0.12, 10}, {0.12, 50}};

pn = ListLinePlot[list1, PlotStyle -> Dashed];

Show[{p1, p2, p3, pn}, Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier to do everything in one plot and to define some helper function and to use "Epilog". E.g.:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
bar = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#[[3]], #[[4]]}} &;
ErrorListPlot[{bar /@ val1, bar /@ val2, bar /@ val3}, 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"m", "n", "s"}, {0.1, 0.8}]}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{0.12, 0}, {0.12, 50}}]}]
```

[image]

P.S. The error you observed was due to the plot range. MMA takes the first it meets and this excluded the third entry.

Answer (score 11):

The `ErrorBar` functionality has been superseded by `Around` and `VectorAround` objects. Sample usage is presented below.

```
Clear[v1, v2, v3]
v1 = VectorAround[{0.12, 10}, {0.01, 1}];
v2 = VectorAround[{0.12, 20}, {0.01, 2}];
v3 = VectorAround[{0.12, 30}, {0.01, 3}];

ListPlot[List /@ {v1, v2, v3}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 0.2}, {0, 35}}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[
    {Red, Green, Blue}, {"m", "n", "s"}
    , LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"]
   , {0.9, 0.5}
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Daniel Huber  I wanted to thank you for helping. you solved my problem

Comment: Dear @Syed, I sincerely appreciate your help